# Gradle new version and Build version

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-build, android-build-type

I have updated SDK and I am using Android studio 2.0(preview). So I think all things are enough updated. For me and for my newly created projects all things work fine. But When Ever I download the code from github I always gets error of gradle versions.

So It is kind of annoying. Well I admire a lot of things are already fixed by gradle while importing that github project .  But once the gradle version error occur its some times gets hard to know the exact reason. And honestly I know things about gradle quite enough , but I always get it solved by hit and trial method. So I have many confusions which I am posting below as a questions

1. How to know what is new gradle version is going on.
2. How to know which things are now forbidden in the new version of gradle
3. How to know which support dependencies will work with new gradle version
4. How to know which version of build tools will perfectly match to gradle.

I think there are many stupid things in these question and I google these questions, but end up with deciding to ask you guys as you guys can clear me formally and casually.

please answer my question if you know this thing deeply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Android Gradle Build systems are software tools designed to automate
>   the process of program compilation .

**How to know what is new gradle version is going on.**

> The Android build system uses the Android Plugin for Gradle to support
>   building Android applications with the Gradle build toolkit. The
>   plugin runs independent of Android Studio so the plugin and the Gradle
>   build system can be updated independently of Android Studio.

You can **Mouse Hover** On **classpath** for checking latest Version .

[image]

**How to know which things are now forbidden in the new version of gradle**

You should check **[Android Plugin for Gradle Release Notes](http://developer.android.com/intl/in/tools/revisions/gradle-plugin.html)**

For **classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.1'**

1. Fixed the **[ZipAlign](http://developer.android.com/intl/in/tools/help/zipalign.html)** task to properly consume the output of the
   previous task when using a customized filename.
2. Fixed **[Renderscript](http://developer.android.com/intl/in/guide/topics/renderscript/compute.html)** packaging with the NDK.
3. Maintained support for the ***createDebugCoverageReport*** build task.
4. Fixed support for customized use of the ***archiveBaseName*** property in
   the `build.gradle build>` file.
5. Fixed the Invalid **ResourceType** **[lint](http://developer.android.com/intl/in/tools/help/lint.html)** warning caused by parameter
   method annotation lookup when running lint outside of Android
   Studio.

Now For your **`3rd and 4th`** questions you should check manual testing .